# Prove that the sign of a function is the same

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm having troubles with a proof from my Calculus book (J. Marsden, A. Weinstein) that I'd like to understand before my classes. Exercise looks like that:

*Prove that if f is continuous on an interval I (not necessarily closed) and f(x) $\neq$ 0 for all x in I, then the sign of f(x) is the same for all x in I.*

The problem is like... I know that it's true but I don't know what does the proof looks like. I did many exercises before but it was the only one that stopped me. Could somebody please show me the proof? I will be very grateful!

Comment: This is an application of the intermediate value theorem.  Suppose there is a function that is changes sign in the interval and is continuous.  Then what does the IVT say about this function?

Comment: I see that now, thanks. I believe that (I will copy it from my previous comment):

That at some point it goes through zero? That comes to my mind. And in my question f(x) is never equal to zero, so it means that it must stay on one side of the plane. I believe that what I said is correct and it should prove that. But is it a proof?

Comment: It is a "proof by contradiction."  You attempt to prove the opposite conclusion, until it leads you to a contradiction.  It will help for whoever is reading your proofs that you say that you will be using a proof by contradiction at the very beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If the sign was sometimes postive and sometimes negative, what would you be able to deduce from the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: That at some point it goes through zero? That comes to my mind. And in my question f(x) is never equal to zero, so it means that it must stay on one side of the plane. I believe that what I said is correct and it should prove that. But is it a proof?

Comment: Yes, it is. If $f(x)>0>f(y)$ then, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $z$ such that $f(z)=0$. But then we reach a contradiction, since were are assuming that $f$ is *never* $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this. If a function, $f$, is positive and continuous, it will "stay" above the x-axis. If $f$ is negative, it will "stay" below the x-axis. In order for a continuous function to change signs, it must cross the x-axis (the line $y=0$). However, $f(x) \neq 0$, so this is impossible. We could use a proof by contradiction to prove this formally (which I will leave up to you).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do this.

Comment: @Miszka Happy to help.